# SELECT a certain quantity of keys from DB (oldest first) and SET key's value to USED

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a function that creates a column of codes into an XLS file from a mysql table,
I have this:

```
function XLSCreate($prodcode, $quantity, $creator, $requestID){

$folderloc = "requestFiles/" . $requestID . "/";
$filename = $creator . "Keys_1";
$finalloc = $folderloc . $filename . "xls";

$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer('$finalloc');
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('$filename');
$worksheet->SetColumn(0, 0, 30);

$query = "SELECT key FROM keysdb WHERE productcode='{$prodcode}' AND used='0' ORDER BY dateLoaded ASC LIMIT {$quantity}";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$j = 1;
while($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
                $worksheet->write($j, 0, $result_array[$i]);
    $j++;
}

$workbook->close();
```

I would like to SET used to "1" when the query runs. How do I do a SET and SELECT at the same time? SO that UNUSED codes are pulled from the database but then after they are outputted (select) to the excel spreadsheet then they are marked as used.

Also, I haven't tested the entire function yet, let me know if something seems amiss.

(Using Pear's Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer, code source from: http://www.technoreaders.com/2008/10/28/spreadsheet-excel-writer/ Have only one column of data, no header)

Answer (score 0):

You would set them processed in the end of the script when the workbook has been closed in 1 query. Use transactions for safety.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a separate query to set the used column to 1. You cant do it in one query.

Comment: How would I do this? From within the while loop? I'm just worried that if while these keys are selected a database change happens (new keys are added) then there'd be no way to update the same keys as were retrieved.

Comment: Keys aren't ENTIRELY unique. They're unique based on creator-key pair.